# Need help refining my Access visual basic code to break out text file into columns

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a text file that looks like the image below

[image]

This is my Access visual basic code that takes those 3 lines and puts them into columns

```
Sub ImportMyFile()
Const strFile As String = "C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\new.txt"
Dim strLine As String
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim i As Byte

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table2")

Open strFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)
i = i + 1
Line Input #1, strLine

If i = 1 Then
rs.AddNew
rs!Category_NM = strLine
ElseIf i = 2 Then
rs!Activity_Nm = Mid(strLine, 10)
ElseIf i = 3 Then
rs!Class_Nm = Mid(strLine, 7)
End If

If i = 4 Or EOF(1) Then
rs.Update
i = 0
End If
Loop
Close #1
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Problem is that i have some sections that contain 4 lines where the name is split in 2. for example

```
You
Tube
package: com.google.android.youtube
class: com.google.android.youtube.app.honeycomb.Shell$HomeActivity
```

How can i account for this in my code?

I either need to just leave the "Tube" out and keep the "You" OR combine them "You Tube"

I am working with hundreds of thousands of code and really would like something automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's use i as flag 
    0 - need to add record
    1 - set category
    2 - set package
    3 - set class & update recordset

```
Sub ImportMyFile()
Const strFile As String = "C:\Users\Samuel\Desktop\new.txt"
Dim strLine As String
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim i As Byte

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table2")

Open strFile For Input As #1
Do Until EOF(1)

    Line Input #1, strLine

    If i = 0 Then
        rs.AddNew
        i = 1
    end if

    If left(strLine, 6) = "class:" Then
        rs!Class_Nm = Mid(strLine, 7)
        i = 3
    End If

    If left(strLine, 8) = "package:" Then
        rs!Activity_Nm = Mid(strLine, 10)
        i = 2
    end if

    If i = 1 Then
        rs!Category_NM = rs!Category_NM & " " & strLine
    end if

    If i=3 or EOF(1) Then
        rs.Update
        i = 0
    End If
Loop
Close #1
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Im trying to get all my data in and now i get an error. Im trying to import 1 million lines from txt file and i got "the field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add" error. Then i tried 400k lines and same erro. anything i can do?

Comment: you have to debug. when error has raised check strLine value and field's size.

Comment: I just says strLine = "Music Player. Not sure why its doing this now. It worked great the first time. I even tried using the same txt file and get this error

Comment: It doesnt seem to be making it off the first line of my text file.

Comment: I dont understand how it worked so well the first time and now it doesn't work. i recreated an entire new database just like it was before an still get that error. i even made the text file only 20 lines.

Comment: rs!Category_NM = rs!Category_NM & " " & strLine

Comment: It says Category_NM is null. strLine = "Music Player.

Comment: and what type and size Category_NM is?

Comment: Short Text, 255.... I found the original txt files that imported originally and it works. it has 117k lines. But when i try to import a 400k or only 10 line txt file i get this error. But that original one is working. how can i find what line in the text file is causing issue? Camera is the first line of the text file

Comment: Now i think i see the problem. in the old file i am importing that is working its in ANSI CR+LF format. In the new file im trying to import its in UTF-8 LF format. I do get foreign characters in my data like "Групова игра" and on the original file that was importing to access those foriegn characters got replaces with question marks. Is there  a way to keep the foreign characters in tact?

Comment: try to add 'strLine=StrConv(strLine, vbFromUnicode)' after 'Line Input #1, strLine'